# How get a full memory dump of a running services.exe instance?

Tags: windows, memory, windbg, memory-dump

How can I get a full memory dump from a `services.exe` process on Windows 8.1 x64?

Comment: It's a lot more convoluted than I expected. A good tutorial can be found [here](http://debugandconquer.blogspot.be/2014/11/taking-memory-dump-of-protected-process.html) but it's not for the faint of heart.